# stacking html element vertically

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

How can I avoid the overlapping of the li elements when rotated as shown below in CSS?

```css
.nav-tabs-left{
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
.nav-tabs-left li{
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav-tabs-left" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><span>Settings</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

**output**

[image]

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using CSS Transforms, you should look into `writing-mode`.

> The writing-mode property defines whether lines of text are laid out horizontally or vertically and the direction in which blocks progress.

IE8 [does not support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d) 2D transforms, whereas there is [partial support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-writing-mode) for writing-mode.

The global support for `writing-mode` is 91.85% and this is really good.

```
.section-title {
    writing-mode: vertical-lr;
}
```

[Source - CSS Writing Mode](https://ishadeed.com/article/css-writing-mode/)

---

[Codepen demo](http://codepen.io/mrshannonyoung/pen/QKrKqW)

Answer (score 2):

Add `display: inline-block;` and a width definition to `.nav-tabs-left li`, like

```
.nav-tabs-left li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

Heres a codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pEAEZJ

Comment: Johannes, thanks for your answer! But I wanted list items stacked not side by side. Shanon Young got the point!